# insert date and time intosql server

Tags: c#

```
        textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
        textBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {

            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into datee (date_m,heur_m)values('" +textBox1.Text + "','" +textBox2.Text + "'", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("succes");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use string concatenation to form a query, because it leads to sql injection.

Comment: Other than [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) messing up your application, what are you asking?

Comment: ***LOUD ALARM NOISE*** SQL Injection Alert!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime result;
string s = String.Format("{0} {1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out result))
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO datee (date_m) VALUES (@value)", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", result);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Here `date_m` column has `datetime` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
textBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

using(var cn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand("", cn)
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO datee(date_m,heur_m) VALUES (@sqltime, @sqltime1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@sqlTime, textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@sqlTime1, textBox2.Text);
        cn.open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```